# Using WinJS.Class and access properties

Tags: javascript, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

Please have a look at the following code:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var game = WinJS.Class.define(
        null,
        {
            width: {
                get: function() {
                    return window.innerWidth;
                }
            },

            height: {
                get: function() {
                    return window.innerHeight;
                }
            },

            run: function() {
                // this.width and this.height is undefined
                Crafty.init(this.width, this.height);
                Crafty.canvas.init();
            }
        }
    );

    WinJS.Namespace.define("MyNamespace", {
        Game: new game()
    });

    window.addEventListener('load', MyNamespace.Game.run);
})();
```

I'm trying to access the public properties `width` and `height` within the `run` method. I'm getting the message, that `this.width` is undefined.

How can I access them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for this. It seems as if `WinJS.Namespace.define` wants to have a class definition rather than an instantiated object. I changed the code to this:

```
(function() {
    "use strict";

    var gameClass = WinJS.Class.define(
        null,
        {
            width: {
                get: function() {
                    return window.innerWidth;
                }
            },

            height: {
                get: function() {
                    return window.innerHeight;
                }
            },

            run: function() {
                // this.width and this.height is undefined
                Crafty.init(this.width, this.height);
                Crafty.canvas.init();
            }
        }
    );

    var game = new gameClass();

    WinJS.Namespace.define("MyNamespace", {
        Game: {
            get: function() {
                return game;
            }
        }
    });

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        MyNamespace.Game.run();
    });
})();
```

Now it is working :)